# SYSWOW64 folder does not exist

Tags: odbc, windows-10

I have windows 10 and I need to run the `odbcad32.exe` in order to create a 32-bit driver but the `c:/windows/SYSWOW64` does not exist..Can I find it somewhere or is there an alternative?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The most likely reason would be that you have a 32-bit version of Windows 10. Yes, that's still a thing.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure your Windows 10 is 64-bit?  Is there a `C:\Program Files (x86)\`?

If not, you're probably running 32-bit Windows 10, and `C:\Windows\System32\odbcad32.exe` is what you need to use.

If so, there's probably something very wrong with your Windows environment and/or installation.